# How do I add a dropdown to change endRow value in a chart displaying date from an HTML table

Tags: highcharts

This displays nicely data from an HTML table on the same page. How can I add a dropdown to let a user change the value of endRow (say, from default value of 10 up to 20, for example)?

```
$(function(mychart) {
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            data: {
                table: document.getElementById('datatable'),
                startRow: 0,
                endRow: 10
            },              
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
              },
            title: {
                text: 'Tides for: Cundy Harbor, New Meadows River, Casco Bay, Maine'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                  text: 'Height of tide<br>in feet.'
                    },
                    gridLineColor: '#197F07',
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    lineWidth:1,
                    plotLines: [{
                        color: '#FF0000',
                        width: 1,
                        value: 0
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br>' +
                        this.point.y + ' ft.<br>' + this.point.name;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it by using the `chart.update` feature. Rest of the work is related to HTML/JS functionalities.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8sz5hwqx/

```
let startRow = document.getElementById("startRow"),
  endRow = document.getElementById("endRow"),
  submit = document.getElementById("submit");


for(let i = 0; i < 134; i ++){
     startRow.options[startRow.options.length] = new Option('start row:' + i, i);
     endRow.options[endRow.options.length] = new Option('end row:' + (i + 1), i + 1);
}

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    chart.update({
        data: {
            startRow: startRow.value,
            endRow: endRow.value
        }
    })
})
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update